# Primefaces: version is not getting appended in the generated HTML

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, version-control

I am using the solution given in [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used) But the version is not getting appended in the generated HTML and latest css is not being picked up. I am using primefaces 5.3.

Comment: Can't reproduce it with PF 5.3 and latest Mojarra version (2.2.12 as of now) on a blank scratchpad project. So the cause of your problem is not visible in the information provided so far. Carefully read first section of http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info how to ask the right question and provide a MCVE.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC, Please find the required information below :    **code in my xhtml** : `<h:outputStyleSheet library="primefaces-customtheme" name="myFile.min.css"/>`. **Genarated output** : `<link "href="/myProject/javax.faces.resource/myFile.min.css?in=primefaces-customtheme&conversationContext=2"` My css file **'myFile.min.css'** is placed at : `src/main/webapp/resources/1_1/primefaces-customtheme/myFile.min.css`

Comment: `conversationContext` suggests some other library is involved which broke this all. Orchestra perhaps? Nonetheless, requests on CSS resources doesn't need to be conversation scoped at all. And, you should really learn creating a MCVE. This way you can exclude influence of 3rd party libraries all on your own.

Comment: @BalusC, thanks for the quick reply. You are right maybe orchestra is causing the problem. Is there a way to debug the problem or can you suggest any solution for this.

Comment: Report a bug to Orchestra guys. Or, get rid of it and migrate to CDI. Orchestra is designed with JSF 1.x in mind and not really 100% JSF 2.x targeted.